# Which "kind" of JavaScript is available inside a map and/or reduce function in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mapreduce, ecmascript-5

Starting from version 2.4 MongoDB uses the V8 engine, thus ECMA-262 5th edition. When running MapReduce jobs **inside the shell**, there is a list of additional [supported function](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce).

What If I **use the native Node.js driver** to run a mapReduce job? Will I be able to use any module or JavaScript function inside `map` and `reduce`?

**Edit**: I can't do some tests right now to figure it out, but I'll update the question ASAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapReduce runs within the MongoDB instance.

You can't use any other programming language or platform to create a MapReduce right now. You could simulate the concept I suppose, but it would mean all data was transferred to your application, etc.

The body of the function is transferred from the Node.JS process to MongoDB (and shards, etc.) by calling `toString` on the provided `map` function (see [here](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/lib/mongodb/collection.js#L1201)).

```
if ('function' === typeof map) {
    map = map.toString();
}
```

You could embed functions in the `map` function, but you'd want to confirm that the performance met your needs as the complexity of the function increases. But, it still would be limited to the function you passed, and could not access other script in Node.JS that might be executing.

**Edit:**

Also, you could use the `scope` parameter of the `mapReduce` call to attach additional functions. If for example, you passed a `scope` as:

```
{ add10: function(v) { return v + 10; } }
```

The function called `add10` would be available in the `map` call (and also the `reduce` and `finalize` functions):

```
var fancyMath = add10(this.total);
```

So, using that technique, you could pass some limited functionality. It does get serialized as BSON and sent to the MongoDB servers, so it needs to be self-contained (and not reference other JavaScript functions that won't be available locally).

Comment: Fine, thanks. What about passing a Node module with the `scope ` argument?

Comment: @Gremo Will not work, the module will be serialised to BSON and will not be deserializable on the other end

Comment: @Gremo - What are you trying to do? You can only access one document at a time anyway... (I'd worry that you're trying to do too much in a MapReduce).

Comment: @WiredPrairie: I could think of wanting to use a library of helper functions, for example for string manipulation. How to make that available in the global scope of the MongoDB execution context?

Comment: @WiredPrairie don't worry :) I'm not trying to do anything "strange". I'm doing a research work, trying to figure out how  things work. Anyway - as suggested by Bergi - a common set of helpers would be a good idea.

Comment: @Bergi - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/ (but it's not recommended)

Comment: Documents can also contain functions as properties. Wondering if `this.func()` works inside `map` or `reduce`...

Comment: @Gremo technically yes, the JS engine will evaluate field values into objects/closures

Comment: And to add to @Sammaye's comment, it would mean that every document would need the extra functions if you wanted them universally available.

Comment: So, to accept the answer and close the question, the definite answer would be "plain javascript functions" passed with the `scope` parameter, but not "complex" Node modules?

Comment: @Gremo Yes a JS closure should be deserialisable from the `scope` variable.

Comment: I did a quick test using the shell to confirm that a function attached to `scope` is available within a `map` function. I edited my answer to reflect this. (I'd still recommend keeping them simple, as I don't consider debugging them fun! :)  ).